# How can I suppress itemize indent only when used inside a quote environment?

Tags: xetex

Using XeTeX, I've written my book with 5.25" pages. That doesn't leave much room for indentation.

LaTeX indents `itemize` *inside* quote environments. That means the items are indented twice: once for the `quote` and a second time for the `itemize`. This looks terrible, so I'd like to eliminate extra left margin for `itemize` items inside quote environments. This is how it looks now:

```
regular text
  * regular bullet
    block quote
      * bullet inside block quote
```

This is what I'd like to have (I think)

```
regular text
  * regular bullet
    block quote
    * bullet inside block quote
```

I'm open to suggestions if that's not the recommended way to go. I'm trying to figure out the best indentation rules for relatively narrow pages. There are a lot of blockquotes in the book.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[openleft]{book}
\usepackage[paperheight=8in,paperwidth=5.25in,left=0.75in,right=0.75in,top=0.75in,bottom=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}

Normal text. I modeled my book on another book I had laying around. The pages are 5.25" wide with 7.5" margins. That's a little thin once you start indenting for block quotes, but I am not going to switch page sizes, because I'm happy with the artwork and the look / size of the book. \blindtext

\begin{itemize}
    \item bullet

    \item bullet

    \item bullet
\end{itemize}

\begin{quote}
    This quote is indented, which looks nice, but I'm not sure it isn't too much. \blindtext

    \begin{itemize}
        \item These bullets (inside quote environments) are indented twice. That's the one thing I'm sure I want to fix.

        \item These bullets (inside quote environments) are indented twice. That's the one thing I'm sure I want to fix.

        \item These bullets (inside quote environments) are indented twice. That's the one thing I'm sure I want to fix.

    \end{itemize}

    \blindtext
\end{quote}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic: `left=0.75in,right=0.75in,top=0.75in,bottom=0.75in` may be expressed more succinctly as `margin=0.75in`.

Comment: Are you sure about the claim that "Itemize outside quote environments does not indent unless I have `\usepackage{parskip}`"?

Comment: @Mico, I'm slapping my forehead with my palm now. I tested with a short paragraph. Without parskip, the short paragraph was indented. Since it was only one line, the paragraph and bullets were on the same left margin. Will edit post. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid left-indentation of bullet symbols and associated text in `itemize` environments, I suggest you load the [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package and write

```
\begin{itemize}[left=0pt]
```

instead of just `\begin{itemize}`. This works both inside and outside `quote` environments.

Comment: I was hoping there was a css-ish way to say "this is how an inner environment,  itemize, will behave inside an outer environment, quote." Is that not the case?

Comment: @Shay - I'm not aware off css-ish methods being available in LaTeX. Sorry.

Comment: @Shay - Since quote is a trivlist, it gets treated like any other nested list environment.  It just has a built in `\item`.